# Decomposable polynomails of 2 degree in finite space $\mathbb{F}[X]$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How can I show that there is a decomposable polynomial of second degree in a finite space $\mathbb{F}[X]$? I tried contrapositive proof but I got stuck. That made me think that maybe I should go for the number of possibilities of polynomials in a finite space. Is this the right way?

Comment: $x(x-1)$ is a decomposable polynomial over every $\mathbb F[X]$.  Are you sure you don't mean "irredicuble"?

Comment: $\mathbb F[X]$ is the polynomial ring over (the field?) $\mathbb F$? In what sense do you mean that $\mathbb F[X]$ is finite?

Comment: I mean that I want to prove it for any finite field such as $\mathbb{Z}_n$ or any other finit field.